# Reducing time complexity to find square Integers

Tags: javascript, math, time-complexity

The following function is to search the square Integers between the range a and b.
But the problem is it is exceeding the time limit.
The range may be 1<=a<=b<=10^9.

```
function squares(a, b) {
    let count = 0;
    while(a<=b)
    {
        if(Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(a)))
        {
            count++;
        }
        a++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

can anyone help me in reducing the complexity of this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking if a number is a perfect square, you could try to "create" them.

> One idea you could have is to find one, then generate the next one, as `(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1`. This would be pretty efficient, but we could do a lot better.

Since, you only need to count the square numbers, we could simply calculate the square roots of a and b. And count the number of integers between those square roots (just subtract one from the other). But be careful when one of a and b is a square itself.

Therefore, we can write the following:

```js
function squares(a, b) {
    const sqrtA = Math.sqrt(a)
    const floorA = Math.floor(sqrtA)
    const sqrtB = Math.sqrt(b)
    const ceilB = Math.floor(sqrtB)
    
    let n = ceilB -  floorA
    
    if (floorA == sqrtA) { // A is a square
        n += 1
    }
    
    return n
}
```